# Proving or disproving we can embed a space $X$ in $Y$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Looking at the question: [Embeddability of the cone of Klein bottle to $\mathbb R^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354991/embeddability-of-the-cone-of-klein-bottle-to-mathbb-r4)

got me thinking about what methods there are for proving or disproving that a topological space $X$ can embed in another topological space $Y$. Obviously in order to prove that one space embeds into another we can explicitly construct a map. This can be extremely difficult though because there may not exist a tame embedding of a space $X$ in a space $Y$ and only wild embeddings which are in general not easy to construct.

So how can we in general show that a space $X$ embeds into $Y$ without constructing an explicit embedding and how can we show that an embedding cannot exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the embedding theorems I know come with constructions, some more explicit than others, of the required embedding. Some embeddings are made explicitly from other functions, others are the result of a limit process or recursive process that can be shown to have the right properties.

Examples of the latter are: every countable linear order embeds into $\mathbb{Q}$, which has a nice recursive proof. 
That an uncountable linear order could never be so embedded is of course trivial from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

An example of the former: every $T_0$ topological space $X$ can be embedded into a product of copies of the two-point Sierpinski space $S = (\{0,1\}, \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}\})$. The proof is just that for every open set $O$ of $X$ we pick $f_O: X \to S$ defined by $f_O(x) = 0$ if $x \in O$, $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in X\setminus O$. These maps are all continuous, and a standard embedding theorem tells us that $e(x) = (f_O(x))_{O \in \mathcal{T}_X}$ is an embedding of $X$ into $\prod_{O \in \mathcal{T}_X} S$. 
Because all products and subspaces of $T_0$ spaces are also $T_0$, it's only $T_0$ spaces for which this can work. So there are good reasons for non-embeddibility.
A similar example we have in Tychonoff spaces and products of $[0,1]$ (Tychonoff cubes).

It's also a well-known embedding theorem (more alnog your lines, I think) that says that any separable metric space with $\dim(X) = n$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, and for compact (differential) manifolds this can be improved to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. The proof of the first embedding (that I know of) is a limiting process of mapping into Nöbeling space, and the second one uses machinery from differential manifolds and integration, IIRC.

Non-embedding theorems can be hard (one of the simplest cases for dimension being the "utilities graph" $K_{3,3}$ not being planar (embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^2$). (The graph is a compact one-dimensional simplex, but not a manifold, so no problem with the second theorem above), and all graphs can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (but this is quite explicitly possible and needs no big theorems per se) 
The non-embeddibility follows in this case from arguments involving Euler characteristic : there is a property of the plane that inherits down to its sub-simplices, and $K_{3,3}$ does not have it.