# Coning a manifold into the same dimension

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^d$ where $d$ is minimal (that is, $X \not \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{d-1}$). When $X$ is the $(d-1)$-sphere, then the cone of $X$ still embeds into $\mathbb R^d$.

Are there any other manifolds $X$ which have this property?

(Related is [Embeddability of the cone of Klein bottle to $\mathbb R^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354991/embeddability-of-the-cone-of-klein-bottle-to-mathbb-r4), where $X$ is the Klein Bottle)

Comment: What category are you working in: PL or topological?

Comment: Triangulable manifolds, to be exact. PL is good too. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: PL is not the same as triangulable.

Comment: Right, but PL manifolds are a subset of triangulable ones. I meant to say that an answer to either class is fine, and the question in my comment asked if there was a difference (in the answer to this question) between PL and topological manifolds.